# Collecting cards with varying frequency

Tags: probability

See https://mathoverflow.net/a/26241/47296.  If one wants to collect at least one instance for each of $n$ elements in a set, the expected number of samples when instances arrive with uniform frequency is:

$$
n \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}
$$

This needs a correction for the natural case where the number of all instances is accurately known, and they arrive according to some distribution known to be non-uniform, but at the moment it is not coming to me.  What is the correction?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard.  The usual solution for equal frequency depends on the fact that the frequency is equal.  That means that after you have collected $i$ of the elements, you don't care which $i$ they are.  If the frequencies vary, you care which ones you have already.  The loss of that symmetry makes the problem much harder.  The other extreme is not too hard-in most collection contests there is one element that is very rare.  The assumption is that everybody who finds one already has all the rest.  If that element is very rare, that is a reasonable assumption.  How rare?  Not very.  If it is rare enough that you already have on average 3 or 4 of each other, you will have them all with high probability.